# Vertically align text inside a Bootstrap alert without using line-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, web-frontend

I am looking to vertically align text content inside my Bootstrap 4 alerts, crucially *without* using `line-height` and ideally without absolute positioning.

My alert looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        Your free trial will expire on <b>23-May-2022</b>. To retain your subscription after this date you can <a href="/admin/crmpicco-gvb-trial/plan">upgrade</a> to one of our paid plans.
</div>
```

My SCSS declaration below does work:

```
.alert.alert-info {
  border: 1px solid #0f6fc5;
  background: #EAF2FA;
  color: #212529;
  min-height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

However, it removes the spacing around then `<b>` and `<a>` tags.

Is there a way to fix this to respect the spacing without a hacky `margin` solution to the `b` and `a` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe enlcosed your text to a span?? Is this what you mean?

```css
.alert.alert-info {
  border: 1px solid #0f6fc5;
  background: #EAF2FA;
  color: #212529;
  min-height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <span>Your free trial will expire on <b>23-May-2022</b>. To retain your subscription after this date you can <a href="/admin/crmpicco-gvb-trial/plan">upgrade</a> to one of our paid plans.</span>
</div>
```